# Limit line breaks in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a text area, where i want to allow users to make line break by pressing enter, but i want to limit that to only one break, because then the users could add as many breaks they want, creating huge white space in the output.

```
  <textarea maxLength={3000} onChange={(e) => setPersonBio(e.target.value)} value={personBio} type="text" rows="5" className="bio-content" placeholder="Enter something about yourself..."></textarea>
```

And then i display it in `<p>` tag with `white-space: pre-line;`

My question is how to limit the amount of breaks user can enter, or delete the additional ones after submitting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`String` methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_search.asp) `search` and `include` inside a `while` loop to remove all but one of a given repeated character.

```js
text = "abc\n\n\ndef\n\nghi"; 
document.write('<textarea rows=6>'+text+'</textarea>');
while (text.includes("\n\n"))
  text = text.replace("\n\n","\n");
document.write('<textarea rows=6>'+text+'</textarea>');
```

Comment: I feel like this is the best solution. But note - for UX purposes it is better to allow them to do what they want in the textarea and run this after the user submits (as opposed to checking as they type), then run this code after they submit before saving to the database. Also, I changed to search for 3 line breaks instead of 2 and replace with 1 in the while loop. This is if you want to allow 2 line breaks but not more than that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```html
 <textarea maxLength={3000} onChange=textAreaChange(e) value={personBio} type="text" rows="5" className="bio-content" placeholder="Enter something about yourself..."></textarea>
```

```js
var pre="";
function textAreaChange(e){
    if(e.target.value.split("\n").length>1){
        e.target.value=pre;
        return;
    };
    setPersonBio(e.target.value);
    pre=e.target.value;
};
```

Add the javascript to where you keep all your other javascript for this site.